# Can't compare datetime in Postgresql sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'time.struct_time'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following database structure using SQLAlchemy using Postgresql with Flask:

```
class Attendance(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True))
```

When I get a date from the user and try and query it against the date of the models:

```
from_date = time.strptime(request.args['from_attendance'],'%m/%d/%Y')
to_date = time.strptime(request.args['to_attendance'],'%m/%d/%Y')
dates = Attendance.query.filter(Attendance.time < from_date,Attendance.time > to_date).all()
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'time.struct_time' 'SELECT attendance.id     AS attendance_id, attendance.time AS attendance_time, attendance.status AS attendance_status,........
```

I believe this is a postgresql specific issue, but I am really at a loss for words.

Comment: What happens if you pass the dates as strings in the from YYYY-MM-DD as string rather than a struct_time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datetime columns in Flask-SQLAlchemy are `datetime` objects. You're using `time` module to parse.

Try:

```
from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.args['from_attendance'],'%m/%d/%Y')
```